# Two Jquery effects at the same time (bootstrap submenu)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, submenu, effects

I'm trying to apply two JQuery effects at the same time to begin when I open and close the bootstrap submenu. These effects are slide and fade, but just fade is running fine.

My Code is:

```
$('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e){
 $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').fadeIn("slow");
 $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').slideDown();
});
$('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e){
 $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').fadeOut("slow");
 $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').slideUp();
});
```

Can someone explain what is wrong with my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thats how I fixed

```
$('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e){
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').animate({
        opacity: 'toggle',
        height: 'toggle'
    },"slow");
}); 

$('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e){
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').animate({
        opacity: 'toggle',
        height: 'toggle',
    },"slow");
});
```